# Issue with loading resources of a common silverlight dll

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, localization

I have few silverlight modules which are using one common silverlight dll. When i localize the application, all module resources are getting loaded properly depending on the selected culture, but not the resources for common dll. For common dll, it is showing always default strings (which are in English) though i have copied the localized dll in correct path. Do i need to do any extra step here?